# What's the difference between あまり and ほど when saying 'so much...that'?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between あまり and ほど when saying 'so much...that'?

For example:

> トムは驚きのあまり何も言えなかった。
>   Tom was so surprised that he was speechless.
>
> トムは驚くほど何も言えなかった。
>   (Tom was so surprised that he was speechless.）？

Or:

> ピンが落ちた音が聞こえるあまり、静かだった。
>   (It was so quiet that you could hear a pin drop.) ？
>
> ピンが落ちた音が聞こえるほど、静かだった。
>   It was so quiet that you could hear a pin drop.

Comment: `ピンを落た音` ← Did you mean to say 「ピンを[落]{お} **とし**た音」,  「ピン**の** [落]{お} **ち**た音」, or 「ピン**が** [落]{お} **ち**た音」?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the main difference lies on whether the focus is placed on the **cause or effect** in a given situation.

Though you will need to change the sentence structure around, you can describe a cause-and-effect situation by using either 「あまり」 or 「ほど」.

> 「(**cause + あまり**) + effect」 places (at least slightly) more  focus on the ***effect***.

「トムは驚{おどろ}きの**あまり**何{なに}も言{い}えなかった。」= "Tom was so surprised that he was speechless."

「静{しず}かな**あまり**、ピンが落{お}ちる音{おと}(が/さえ/さえも)聞{き}こえた。」 = "It was so quiet that you could hear a pin drop."

> 「**(effect + ほど**) + cause」    places (at least slightly) more focus on the ***cause***.

「トムは何も言えない**ほど**驚いた。」 = "Tom was surprised to the extent that he became speechless."

「ピンが落ちる音が聞こえる**ほど**静かだった。」 = "It was quiet to the extent that you could hear a pin drop."

You will need to form/read/hear  hundreds of sentences like these to get a feel of the usages.

Thus, two of your four sentences sound quite awkward and make little sense to us native speakers.  Those are:

「トムは驚くほど何も言えなかった。」

and

「ピンが落ちた音が聞こえるあまり、静かだった。」